# chaining double equals == returns false

Tags: javascript

I have 3 textboxes that I am trying to do some validation that all 3 values match. I have a simple function:

```
    function DoesSubsriberSignatureMatch() {
    return tbNameOfSubscriber.GetText() == tbSubscriberSig1.GetText() == tbSubscriberReEnter.GetText();
}
```

I stepped through with the debugger, and it seems in Javascript in Chrome at least, "a"=="a" returns true, but "a"=="a"=="a" returns false.

Why?

Comment: because `"a"=="a"` is true and `true == "a"` is false?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Coming from Python, perhaps? Most languages don't actually have comparison chaining. Trying it produces nonsense results.

Answer (score 6):

Take

```
"a"=="a"=="a"
```

and break it down.  So first

```
"a" == "a"
```

equals what?  `true`.  Right.  Now substitute `true` in for that first part

```
true == "a"
```

which of course is false

Answer (score 5):

Because `a == a` yields `true`, and `true != a`.

(Unless a holds the value `true`).