# equals comparison operator gives bad result after used four times in a row

Tags: javascript, comparison-operators

I have a class Square with a getter method to determine if a square is valid or not. If my square has sides of 1 my code will return true. If my square has 4 sides of 5 it returns false. Can someone explain what is happening?

As you can see I accessed this in the browser and had the following results:

[image]

```
class Square extends Polygon { 
get isValid() {
    const testArray = Object.values(this); 


    return (testArray[0] == testArray[1] == testArray[2] == testArray[3]) ? true : false

}
```

Comment: See: [chaining double equals == returns false](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20080628)

Answer (score 2):

The expression

```
testArray[0] == testArray[1] == testArray[2] == testArray[3]
```

carries out `==` 3 times, left-to-right.

```
((testArray[0] == testArray[1]) == testArray[2]) == testArray[3]
```

The first time, when the array items are equal, the first will evaluate to `true`:

```
((testArray[0] == testArray[1]) == testArray[2]) == testArray[3]
(true == testArray[2]) == testArray[3]
```

If the items are numbers, the next comparison will *only* return `true` if the item is 1:

```js
console.log(true == 1);
console.log(true == 2);
console.log(true == 5);
```

This is because, when using abstract equality comparison `==`, when a boolean is compared to a number, the boolean is coerced to a number first, and the numeric value for `true` is 1.

```js
console.log(Number(true));
```

The third comparison has the same trouble.

To fix it, instead take the first value (or any value), and use `.every`:

```
const oneVal = testArray[0];
return testArray.every(val => val === oneVal);
```